# Android: What is .APT file

Tags: android

I created and android app for my client, he is asking me to give .apt file. I don't have any such idea about .apt file. I confirmed whether he is looking for .apk or .apt, he said he wants .apt file as well.
Can someone please tell me what is exactly .apt file in android and how can I generate one to give it to my client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.apt is android themes format. I think your client is mistaken unless he expects you to create a new theme.

Comment: No, we are not creating any new theme.

Comment: In this case .apk file is the only thing you should provide. It's not clear why your client wants .apt as well, maybe you should clarify it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

the executable file for an android app is the .apk (android package) file, that's all you need to deliver in this case, hope to help